# Application cannot create log file in UNIX?

Tags: unix, logging, log4j

I have developed a web project. Which is generating log file using log4j. But the same application is deployed in UNIX, it is not able to create log file also..
I'm new to unix.   Why it is not creating log file? 
This is the code....

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO,CA, FA

#Console Appender
log4j.appender.CA = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern =  %d  %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#File Appender
log4j.appender.FA = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File =correspondence.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern = %d  %5p [%t] - %m%n
```

It is creating log file in server installation folder. But not creating in UNIX.. Any changes I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the line:

```
log4j.appender.FA.File =correspondence.log
```

to:

```
log4j.appender.FA.File = /tmp/correspondence.log
```

If it works, then create a log dir in the home directory of the user running the application server, chmod it at least to be executable and writable by owner and then put the log in that directory.

Comment: Hi BigMike, Log file is not creating in Unix manchine. what was the problem?

Comment: probably your app server cannot write in his directory due to privilieges, point the log file to a surely writable path (e.g. /tmp/)